# javascript add key value pair to array checking if exists

Tags: javascript, arrays

In a Laravel application I need to add chartjs graphs in the dashboard.
In particular one of the graphs must be stacked bar.
On the x axis I have the labels represented by taxes, while on the y axis I have the 3 categories of values (paid, unpaid, partially paid).
I then then defined 3 empty arrays A, B, C which I pass to the graph with the correct data.
So to populate the graph I use a script with which I pass the data.
My problem is that the paid, unpaid, partial paid arrays don't have the same length and are composed with the structure:

`arrayX = [{total: value, tax: "Description1"},{},...,{total: value, tax: "DescriptionN"}];`

while the array of `labels=["Description",.........,"DescriptionN"];`

I would need to cycle on the array of labels, if the value is present in the arrayX then I set for `A.push(arrayX.total) otherwise A.push(0.00);`

All this while maintaining the order of the elements.

Do you have any suggestions or advice? Is it possible with Javascript to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map over `labels` trying to find a match in arrayX.

```
   const A = labels.map(l => {
      let data = arrayX.find(el => el.tax === l);
      if (!data)
        return 0;
    
      return data.total;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks James, and it's possible to push into array directly with this loop? i've tried to push if not data and it works, but i need to push the arrayX.total if the condition is true

Comment: Hi I modified the example to only put the total (or 0) into the resulting array.